# Splat (*) operator and attr_extras gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Some time ago I found that [attr_extras](https://github.com/barsoom/attr_extras) gem can be used for creating class attributes.

Writing:

```
class Foo
  attr_private_initialize :bar
end
```

replaces:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end

  private

  attr_reader :bar
end
```

My question is, does `attr_extras` gem support handling splat (`*`) operators in constructors?

I would like to get following result:

```
def initialize(*bar)
  @bar = bar
end
```

I don't see this functionality documented, so I think this is impossible, however maybe someone knows how to do it using this gem?

Comment: `initialize` is just a normal method which happens to be called by `Class#new` when creating objects. It's perfectly valid using splat in `initialize`.

Comment: Yes, but my question is, how to achieve that using attr_extras gem. `attr_private_initialize :*bar` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not support that. Here's [the code](https://github.com/barsoom/attr_extras/blob/c4954f592134cdbd712aa58ca8646f0007b3af35/lib/attr_extras/attr_initialize.rb#L17-L37).

In short, given the dynamic nature of initializer, it *already* defines all arguments as splatted array and then takes it apart into individual values (to be used in readers and whatnot). You can't have nested splats, so it's impossible to do with this gem (the current implementation, anyway).

```
klass.send(:define_method, :initialize) do |*values|
  validate_arity.call(values.length, self.class)

  names.zip(values).each do |name_or_names, value|
    if name_or_names.is_a?(Array)
      hash = value || {}

      known_keys = name_or_names.map { |name| name.to_s.sub(/!\z/, "").to_sym }
      unknown_keys = hash.keys - known_keys
      if unknown_keys.any?
        raise ArgumentError, "Got unknown keys: #{unknown_keys.inspect}; allowed keys: #{known_keys.inspect}"
      end

      name_or_names.each do |name|
        set_ivar_from_hash.call(self, name, hash)
      end
    else
      name = name_or_names
      instance_variable_set("@#{name}", value)
    end
  end

  if block
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end
```